# Using Gulp to Concatenate and Uglify files

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to use Gulp to:

1. Take 3 specific javascript files, concatenate them, then save the result to a file (concat.js)
2. Take this concatenated file and uglify/minify it, then save the result to another file  (uglify.js)

I have the following code so far

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
        gp_concat = require('gulp-concat'),
        gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

    gulp.task('js-fef', function(){
        return gulp.src(['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'])
            .pipe(gp_concat('concat.js'))
            .pipe(gp_uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['js-fef'], function(){});
```

However, the uglify operation doesn't seem to be working, or the file isn't generated for some reason.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Amazed to not see it yet, so I'd just like to quickly remark that the goal in itself somewhat goes against the philosophy of Gulp. Writing of intermediary files is more the Grunt way of working. Gulp promotes streams to improve speed. But I'm sure the guy asking had his reasons :).

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but I've made a npm module to do this kind of work very easily using a yaml file. Check it out : http://github.com/Stnaire/gulp-yaml-packages.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to use `gulp-rename` and also output the concatenated file first before 'uglification'. Here's the code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gp_concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    gp_rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('js-fef', function(){
    return gulp.src(['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'])
        .pipe(gp_concat('concat.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(gp_rename('uglify.js'))
        .pipe(gp_uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js-fef'], function(){});
```

Coming from `grunt` it was a little confusing at first but it makes sense now. I hope it helps the `gulp` noobs.

And, if you need sourcemaps, here's the updated code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gp_concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    gp_rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    gp_sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('js-fef', function(){
    return gulp.src(['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'])
        .pipe(gp_sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(gp_concat('concat.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(gp_rename('uglify.js'))
        .pipe(gp_uglify())
        .pipe(gp_sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js-fef'], function(){});
```

See [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) for more on options and configuration.

**UPDATE - FEB 2022**

These days, it may be easier for you to handle build tasks using Gulp4 and Async/Await functionality:

```
// gulpfile.js

const fs = require('fs/promises');
const concat = require('concat');
const uglify = require('uglify-js');

let files_arr = ['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'];

async function myGulpTask()
{
    var concat_str,
        uglify_str
    ;

    // concat content
    concat_str = await concat(files_arr);

    // save to file
    await fs.writeFile('concat.js', concat_str, 'utf8');

    // uglify content
    uglify_str = await uglify.minify(concat_str, {mangle:false}).code;

    // save to file
    await fs.writeFile('uglify.js', uglify_str, 'utf8');
}

module.exports = {
    myTask: myGulpTask
};
```

Then from the CLI:

```
gulp myTask
```

Comment: FYI, you are missing a single quotation mark before concat.js.

The line after your return statement in `gulp.task` should be: `.pipe(gp_concat('concat.js'))`

Comment: All files are generated, however, in the debugger I still see the minified version. What can be the reason? The map file is named correctly and can be accessed by its URL.

Comment: It will, depends on browsers the original sources are on different tab. You need to put breakpoint there.

Comment: It is not clear for me why we need to do rename? Is it a bug or ?

Comment: @przemcio In my case I wanted a record of all the files at each step in the process. However, if all you care about is the final minified file, then you can of course shorten the gulp file even further

Comment: excuse the noob question: Will this write sourcemaps both for the regular and the minified (uglified) ouput?

Comment: Why do you need to do this twice?   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

Answer (score 18):

My gulp file produces a final compiled-bundle-min.js, hope this helps someone.

[image]

```
//Gulpfile.js

var gulp = require("gulp");
var watch = require("gulp-watch");

var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var del = require("del");
var minifyCSS = require("gulp-minify-css");
var copy = require("gulp-copy");
var bower = require("gulp-bower");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

var path = {
    src: "bower_components/",
    lib: "lib/"
}

var config = {
    jquerysrc: [
        path.src + "jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        path.src + "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js",
        path.src + "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
    ],
    jquerybundle: path.lib + "jquery-bundle.js",
    ngsrc: [
        path.src + "angular/angular.js",
         path.src + "angular-route/angular-route.js",
         path.src + "angular-resource/angular-resource.js"
    ],
    ngbundle: path.lib + "ng-bundle.js",

    //JavaScript files that will be combined into a Bootstrap bundle
    bootstrapsrc: [
        path.src + "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ],
    bootstrapbundle: path.lib + "bootstrap-bundle.js"
}

// Synchronously delete the output script file(s)
gulp.task("clean-scripts", function (cb) {
    del(["lib","dist"], cb);
});

//Create a jquery bundled file
gulp.task("jquery-bundle", ["clean-scripts", "bower-restore"], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.jquerysrc)
     .pipe(concat("jquery-bundle.js"))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("lib"));
});

//Create a angular bundled file
gulp.task("ng-bundle", ["clean-scripts", "bower-restore"], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.ngsrc)
     .pipe(concat("ng-bundle.js"))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("lib"));
});

//Create a bootstrap bundled file
gulp.task("bootstrap-bundle", ["clean-scripts", "bower-restore"], function     () {
    return gulp.src(config.bootstrapsrc)
     .pipe(concat("bootstrap-bundle.js"))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("lib"));
});


// Combine and the vendor files from bower into bundles (output to the Scripts folder)
gulp.task("bundle-scripts", ["jquery-bundle", "ng-bundle", "bootstrap-bundle"], function () {

});

//Restore all bower packages
gulp.task("bower-restore", function () {
    return bower();
});

//build lib scripts
gulp.task("compile-lib", ["bundle-scripts"], function () {
    return gulp.src("lib/*.js")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("compiled-bundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
        .pipe(rename("compiled-bundle.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Comment: Great example @wchoward it was just what i was looking for, very clean straightforward design.

Answer (score 10):

Solution using `gulp-uglify`, `gulp-concat` and `gulp-sourcemaps`. This is from a project I'm working on.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(scripts, {base: '.'})
        .pipe(plumber(plumberOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: false,
            debug: debug,
        }))
        .pipe(gulpif(debug, wrapper({
            header: fileHeader,
        })))
        .pipe(concat('all_the_things.js', {
            newLine:'\n;' // the newline is needed in case the file ends with a line comment, the semi-colon is needed if the last statement wasn't terminated
        }))
        .pipe(uglify({
            output: { // http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/codegen
                beautify: debug,
                comments: debug ? true : /^!|\b(copyright|license)\b|@(preserve|license|cc_on)\b/i,
            },
            compress: { // http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress, http://davidwalsh.name/compress-uglify
                sequences: !debug,
                booleans: !debug,
                conditionals: !debug,
                hoist_funs: false,
                hoist_vars: debug,
                warnings: debug,
            },
            mangle: !debug,
            outSourceMap: true,
            basePath: 'www',
            sourceRoot: '/'
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
            includeContent: true,
            sourceRoot: '/',
        }))
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js'))
});
```

This combines and compresses all your `scripts`, puts them into a file called `all_the_things.js`. The file will end with a special line

```
//# sourceMappingURL=all_the_things.js.map
```

Which tells your browser to look for that map file, which it also writes out.

Answer (score 8):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('create-vendor', function () {
var files = [
    'bower_components/q/q.js',
    'bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js',
    'node_modules/jstorage/jstorage.min.js'
];

return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('scripts'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('scripts'));
});
```

Your solution does not work because you need to save file after concat process and then uglify and save again. You do not need to rename file between concat and uglify.

Comment: I would say it's the prerogative of the developer to decide what they do and do not need when using gulp. In my case, I wanted to rename the files at each step. Others may prefer otherwise.

Comment: Of course, you can decide what is the best option for you. I understood, that answer below says you need to rename file, I just said that you do not need (it is not obligatory), sorry if I made some confusion.

Answer (score 4):

**Jun 10 2015:** Note from the author of `gulp-uglifyjs`:

> **DEPRECATED:** This plugin has been blacklisted as it relies on Uglify to concat the files instead of using gulp-concat, which breaks the "It should do one thing" paradigm. When I created this plugin, there was no way to get source maps to work with gulp, however now there is a gulp-sourcemaps plugin that achieves the same goal. gulp-uglifyjs still works great and gives very granular control over the Uglify execution, I'm just giving you a heads up that other options now exist.

---

**Feb 18 2015:** `gulp-uglify` and `gulp-concat` both work nicely with `gulp-sourcemaps` now. Just make sure to set the `newLine` option correctly for `gulp-concat`; I recommend `\n;`.

---

**Original Answer (Dec 2014):** Use [gulp-uglifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglifyjs) instead. `gulp-concat` isn't necessarily safe; it needs to handle trailing semi-colons correctly. `gulp-uglify` also doesn't support source maps. Here's a snippet from a project I'm working on:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(uglify('all_the_things.js',{
            output: {
                beautify: false
            },
            outSourceMap: true,
            basePath: 'www',
            sourceRoot: '/'
        }))
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js'))
});
```

Comment: Huh? gulp-uglify definitely supports source maps:

https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support

Comment: @MisterOh Not sure it did at the time of writing, or if it did, perhaps `gulp-concat` didn't (`gulp-uglify` won't let you minify multiple files so you have to concat first). Also, `gulp-concat` uses a `\r\n` by default, which *could* cause issues if your JS files don't terminate properly. But yes, now that there's support, it's probably better to go that route as its more flexible.

Comment: @Mark - Would appreciate if you would post the solution with gulp-sourcemaps that works inline with Obinwanne's answer. I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @NightOwl888 [okay](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30600529/65387) Actually, that doesn't produce inline sourcemaps if that's what you were asking; it's still a separate file.

Comment: gulp-uglifyjs is also depecated now. Just using the gulp-uglify plugin should be enough now. See other answers for an up-to-date solution.

Comment: @NeilMonroe Thanks. Added a note to my answer to make it more clear. Keeping this here for history.

Comment: @Mark I don't understand. Firstly, my question made no mention of `gulp-uglifyjs`. Finally, you say `gulp-uglifyjs` is deprecated, use `gulp-uglifyjs` instead?!

Comment: @ObinwanneHill The horizontal rule indicates a section of my answer written during a different time period. I added the "DEPRECATED" warning to the top of my answer just recently. Below is my original answer. I offered `gulp-uglifyjs` as an alternative to `gulp-uglify` because at the time `gulp-uglify` didn't work with sourcemaps but `gulp-uglifyjs` did. I made note of that in my Feb 18th edit.

Answer (score 0):

we are using below configuration to do something similar

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    async = require("async"),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    gulpDS = require("./gulpDS"),
    del = require('del');

// CSS & Less
var jsarr = [gulpDS.jsbundle.mobile, gulpDS.jsbundle.desktop, gulpDS.jsbundle.common];
var cssarr = [gulpDS.cssbundle];

var generateJS = function() {

    jsarr.forEach(function(gulpDSObject) {
        async.map(Object.keys(gulpDSObject), function(key) {
            var val = gulpDSObject[key]
            execGulp(val, key);
        });

    })
}

var generateCSS = function() {
    cssarr.forEach(function(gulpDSObject) {
        async.map(Object.keys(gulpDSObject), function(key) {
            var val = gulpDSObject[key];
            execCSSGulp(val, key);
        })
    })
}

var execGulp = function(arrayOfItems, dest) {
    var destSplit = dest.split("/");
    var file = destSplit.pop();
    del.sync([dest])
    gulp.src(arrayOfItems)
        .pipe(concat(file))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destSplit.join("/")));
}

var execCSSGulp = function(arrayOfItems, dest) {
    var destSplit = dest.split("/");
    var file = destSplit.pop();
    del.sync([dest])
    gulp.src(arrayOfItems)
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(concat(file))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destSplit.join("/")));
}

gulp.task('css', generateCSS);
gulp.task('js', generateJS);

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js']);
```

sample GulpDS file is below:

```
{

    jsbundle: {
        "mobile": {
            "public/javascripts/sample.min.js": ["public/javascripts/a.js", "public/javascripts/mobile/b.js"]
           },
        "desktop": {
            'public/javascripts/sample1.js': ["public/javascripts/c.js", "public/javascripts/d.js"]},
        "common": {
            'public/javascripts/responsive/sample2.js': ['public/javascripts/n.js']
           }
    },
    cssbundle: {
        "public/stylesheets/a.css": "public/stylesheets/less/a.less",
        }
}
```