# How to minify css after concatanation? Issue when using Gulp

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am using the following task in gulp in order to concatenate some CSS files.

Script runs fine and I am able to get a unique file "app-flat.css" with all CSS.
But I am not able to minify  "app-flat.css" using the following line

```
.pipe(minifyCss())
```

I need to minify the result of concat "app-flat.css".

Could you please tell me what is wrong in my script?
Should I place .pipe(minifyCss()) as last process?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var open = require('open');
var jscs = require('gulp-jscs');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var stylish = require('gulp-jscs-stylish');
var sloc = require('gulp-sloc');
var complexity = require('gulp-complexity');

var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var nib = require('nib');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var header = require('gulp-header');
var fs = require('fs');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    gulp.task('theme-flat', function () {
        gulp.src([
            'themes/a/a.css',
            'themes/b/b.css'])
          .pipe(concat('app-flat.css'))
          .pipe(minifyCss())  // problem here
          .pipe(header(fs.readFileSync('copyright.txt', 'utf8')))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/flat/'));
    });
```

Notes: I can use another minifier like uglify or others as I am not limitate to only gulp-minify-css

Comment: This will probably be of your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591854/using-gulp-to-concatenate-and-uglify-files

Comment: @sailens please note my script use gulp-minify-css thanks for your time on this

Comment: Just to be sure : can you paste your var / require ?

Answer (score 2):

You Should add the the concat pipe :

```
gulp.src('src/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'))
    .pipe(concat('app-flat.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, call me out if i'm wrong. You're trying to minify the file after you've already created `app-flat.css` file. You need to `pipe` it through before you pipe `concat`

```
   gulp.task('theme-flat', function () {
        gulp.src([
            'themes/a/a.css',
            'themes/b/b.css'])
          .pipe(minifyCss())  // before you concat you're file
          .pipe(header(fs.readFileSync('copyright.txt', 'utf8')))
          .pipe(concat('app-flat.css'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/flat/'));
    });
```