# ASP.NET MVC how to produce the physical files of each bundle when publishing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

Is it possible to actually get the bundles that the framework would generate in runtime, but as physical files when publishing an application?

For instance, if I have 3 files in a bundle: `a.js`, `b.js` and `c.js` (and/or `a.min.js`, `b.min.js`, `c.min.js`), and I publish the website, I want to get only `mybundle.js` (being its contents the combination in order of a, b and c minified versions).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the combined files at build time, you should look into using a task runner like [gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591854/using-gulp-to-concatenate-and-uglify-files).

Here's a sample from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24597914/26226) in the linked question:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gp_concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    gp_rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('js-fef', function(){
    return gulp.src(['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'])
        .pipe(gp_concat('concat.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(gp_rename('uglify.js'))
        .pipe(gp_uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js-fef'], function(){});
```

If you want the combined files after publishing, you can view the page source in your browser and download the bundle.

Comment: I need to do this with several bundles, so the last idea of view the page source won't be practical. I'll look into your first approach. I guess I was expecting to find something out of the box in the framework or visual studio publishing settings. Thanks

Comment: @zed, the bundling framework isn't designed for build time, but rather run time, so that's all you can do.