# How to compile html template and Javascript into one file

Tags: angularjs, compilation, gulp

I am implementing AngularJS Directive. 
There is an javasctipt file and Html template file under /src folder. 
I want to use Gulp to compile them together, and output to /dist folder. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Why you want to do it? It's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to say that is not a good practice to combine two different extensions file in one.

But if you willing to do, you can achieve it by concatenate the files.

[here is the good one link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591854/using-gulp-to-concatenate-and-uglify-files)

[another link](http://learningwithjb.com/posts/concat-combining-multiple-files-into-one-with-gulp)