# node js minify and concatenate to single file from modular code structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, minify

I have a modularised application based on NodeJS.
The structure of the application looks like

- server.js
- controllers

  - controller1.js
  - controller2.js
- dao

  - dao1.js
  - dao2.js
- node_modules

Now I want to minify and concatenate the entire project into a single file. The challenge I am facing is every controller and dao files are using "**require**" (relative paths) to include the node modules
Is there any easy way to achieve this?

**Edit**

Tried webpack module 
My webpack.config.js looks like

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'))
.filter(x => ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1)
.forEach(mod => { nodeModules[mod] = `commonjs ${mod}`; });

module.exports = {
  name: 'server',
  target: 'node',
  entry: './server.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  externals: nodeModules,
  module: {
    loader: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It is giving this error:

> ERROR in ./~/npm/~/npm-registry-client/test/unpublish-scoped.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./fixtures/@npm/np
>   m-registry-client/cache.json in D:\OTTAFW\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-regi
>   stry-client\test

Comment: What is the point in minify node app?

Comment: I want to share this application and want to keep the code little secured

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at webpack?
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task runner like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to stitch and minify. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591854/using-gulp-to-concatenate-and-uglify-files) if you want to bluntly stitch and minify files. In order to manage dependency you have to define a dependency tree and write the logic so that multiple dependencies are not added in the final build.

```
server.js
controllers
|-- controller1.js
          require('lodash')
|-- controller2.js
          require('./controller1')
dao
|-- dao1.js
          require('lodash')
          require('../controllers/controller2')
|-- dao2.js
          require('../controllers/controller1')
node_modules
```

Hypothetically, if this is the case you have to careful of the fact that the files gets attached only once.

On the contrary, you can use [rollup](http://rollupjs.org)